# Create an album

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application for uploading images and videos. At the moment I am just showing the links in a repeater. I want to display the files grouped as albums. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use some meta data with your files to let your script know how to group them. Ideally this would be stored in a database,  mapping the file to its sorting meta data. that you would then be able to parse through for your desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a DB field to record the filetype extension to facilitate selection. Then use the ListView GroupTemplate to organize the layout:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx